# Debug PostgreSQL sql query

Tags: sql, debugging, postgresql

Is there a way to configure PostgreSQL so that when I run a "delete from table_a;" 
it outputs some information how many entries that was cascade deleted.

I'm running my querys in the cli application.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I found a solution. It was good enough for me, though I wanted a estimated statistics on how many rows that were effected.

This will ouput a list of all constraints triggered by the query.

```
EXPLAIN ANALYZE DELETE FROM table_a;
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a plpgsql trigger function on tables to increment a sequence on a delete to get an exact count.

You would need to reset the sequence before issuing the delete. You could use a different sequence per table to get per table statistics.